# Passing variables to global functions common to both web app and winforms app in .Net

Tags: .net, winforms, variables, web-applications

What is the best way to pass variables to global functions (in BussLogic) which can be used by both web app and winforms app?

I am thinking of declaring structures with variables (which can be accessed within the project by declaring them as friend for winforms app and storing them in session variable for web app) and passing these structures byref to the global functions in buss logic.

Currently I've web app and winforms app both are designed to do the same thing (reading data from database and displaying in grid) and I am trying to get rid of duplicate code.

I am sure there are many other ways to achieve this but not sure which one is the best.

Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

I´m just wondering, how do you plan to pass variables between a windows application and a web application both environments are totally different and have distincs environments, and also it worth to mention that web app are stateless, most of the objects have a per request lifecycle.

instead of sharing variables, why don´t you create a **service layer**, a web service (wcf or asmx) that exposes methods all the business functionallity that you need to re-use and just do your custom programing that are related to the presentation layer.

take a look to the following [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx) that I consider standart for the task you want to acomplish.